# How to make Flasks index.html take file from folder

Tags: python-3.x, http

This is my python3 file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="html/")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

And this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

moive.mp4 is in same folder as index.html but it gets 404 error,but when I change it to

```
src="/html/movie.mp4"
```

I get 200 but it still doesn show when i put It on http server and then use

```
src="http://192.168.0.17/movie.mp4"
```

It work how can I make this work without using server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static files (your `movie.mp4`) should be in a folder called `static/`

Create the link in your template with:

```
<source src='{{ url_for("static", filename="movie.mp4") }}' type="video/mp4">
```

This will automatically render the URL as:

```
/static/movies.mp4
```

---

> moive.mp4 is in same folder as index.html

Templates and static files are not the same thing, hence the reason for separate directories:

- **templates** are loaded by the python application and rendered to produce the HTML which is passed to the browser.
- **static files** are served directly.  When you get to deploying the app, it's common to have a reverse proxy serve these, so any request to `/static` never reaches the app server.

Despite template files commonly having the `html` extension,    these never reach the browser without being processed by the python application first.